# Why won't the makeCopy portion of my script execute properly in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I am a very novice coder and am trying to accomplish the following using a Google Form:

1. Rename file uploaded by user based on name defined by combination of form fields
2. Create a copy of the uploaded file to a specific folder in GDrive, based on answer to particular form question

So far, I have managed to get Part 1 working, but Part 2 doesn't seem to function properly (no error message, just no action). Anyone able to guide me where I'm going wrong?

```js
function fileRename() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
// returns the total number of form submissions
  var length=form.getResponses().length;
//retrieve fileID of document uploaded by user in Question 6 of the form (i.e. Index 5)
  var id=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[5].getResponse();
//getResponses()[length-1] retrieves the last form response, accounting for the fact that the first index is zero and hte last length-1
//gets the form answers used to concatenate the file name
  var fileUploadEntity=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var fileUploadDate=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[3].getResponse();
  var fileUploadType=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
//accesses the uploaded file
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var name = file.getName();
//changes the file name
  var name = fileUploadEntity+'_'+fileUploadDate+'_'+fileUploadType
  file.setName(name);
  
//creates a copy and saves it to the relevant regional shared drive depending on which array the entity belongs to, using its four-letter identifier 
  
  var APAC = ["WRAU", "WRNZ", "WRSG", "WRMY", "WRHK"];
  var NORAM = ["WRCA", "WRCC", "WRCW", "WRUS"];
  var MEA = ["WRKE", "WRUG", "WRSO", "WRSA", "WRRW", "WRTZ", "WRZW"];
  var LATAM = ["WRMX"];
  var EEA = ["WRBE", "WRUK"];
  
  var folderAPAC = DriveApp.getFolderById('1IKIDSEEGHf802WaF4l4ntN9uiUO5jJpa');
  var folderNORAM = DriveApp.getFolderById('1BitldN3Uw7453wxnnI1X5PUmbmTiQn5O'); 
  var folderMEA = DriveApp.getFolderById('18tWR1C-mdO7moAtktOHJsvXjx_V0kdg0');
  var folderLATAM = DriveApp.getFolderById('1cG0iPocn3KyXK8XgaxnZNWVU-HKJ97dX');
  var folderEEA = DriveApp.getFolderById('1N8tB8AjMkR7gRarcwd4NYmry_wh0WVkY');

  if (fileUploadEntity.indexOf(APAC)>-1) { 
 file.makeCopy(name, folderAPAC);
  }
  
  else if (fileUploadEntity.indexOf(NORAM)>-1) {
 file.makeCopy(name, folderNORAM);
  }
  
  else if (fileUploadEntity.indexOf(LATAM)>-1) { 
 file.makeCopy(name, folderLATAM);
  }
  
  else if (fileUploadEntity.indexOf(MEA)>-1) { 
 file.makeCopy(name, folderMEA);
  }
  
  else if (fileUploadEntity.indexOf(EEA)>-1) { 
 file.makeCopy(name, folderEEA);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `typeof fileUploadEntity` and its value?

Comment: I believe that there is currently a bug in Apps Script for the `file.makeCopy(name, folder);` version of the method.  What you can do is make a copy of the file, giving it a name, and then move it to the folder.    `var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(" put ID here");//Logger.log('destination: ' + destination.getName())  newFile = file.makeCopy(name);  newFile.moveTo(destination);`

Comment: Hi Rafa, Thanks for replying. The variable `fileUploadEntity` is a drop-down selector list. It's a required field, and its values are the same as the arrays used for the variables `APAC`, `NORAM`, `MEA`, `LATAM` and `EEA` (i.e. WRAU, WRNZ, WRSG, WRMY, WRHK, WRCA, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is using `indexOf` the wrong way.

Instead of

```
fileUploadEntity.indexOf(APAC)
```

try

```
APAC.indexOf(fileUploadEntity)
```

Do the same or the other places where `indexOf` is used

Reference

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Thanks, @Rubén - that worked perfectly! I appreciate the link to the reference materials so I now better understand how the `indexOf` method works.